# Is it possible to reference value of another watched expression in vs2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

When I hit a breakpoint I have "this" in my watch window

```
this -> 0x2cceb42c
```

I copy that value into a new line in my watch window (it displays both the name and the value in hex)

```
0x2cceb42c -> 0x2cceb42c
```

On a third line I cast my value into a pointer to my class:

```
(MyClass*)0x2cceb42c -> { members of class... }
```

The problem is, next time I run the program the address has changed so I have to edit the address on my third line.  Only, I'm not just using it in the third line, but also in 5 other watch expressions.  Which means the next time I run the program I have to change the address in all 5 watched expressions.

What I would like to do is have my 5 watch expressions refer to the value in line 2 - then I only ever need to change the address in one place and all my watches will update automatically.

Is this possible? Or can anyone suggest a trick to achieve as close to this as possible?

---

Clarification: I want to see the results of my 5 watch expressions when I'm on a breakpoint elsewhere in the code (where "this" is no longer the value I'm interested in, which is why I'm copying the address out of "this").

Comment: Erm, use `(MyClass*)this`.  Do fret a bit over it not having good debug info.

Comment: Thanks - I want to see the results of my 5 watch expressions when I'm on a breakpoint elsewhere in the code (where "this" is no longer the value I'm interested in - hence why I copied the value of "this" and cast it to a MyClass in the first place - sorry - wasn't clear in my initial question)

Comment: Just add a global variable, only for debugging.  Store *this* into it so you can always watch it.  Use #ifdef DEBUG.